# Optional parameter in custom function

Tags: vba, excel

The following custom function takes one optional integer as argument.
If the argument is missing, should return 1.
If the argument was passed, should return the argument value.

The problem: if the argument is missing, the function returns 0 instead of 1.

any thoughts?

```
Function f(Optional i As Integer) As Integer
If IsMissing(i) Then
f = 1
Else
f = i
End If
End Function
```

Comment: `IsMissing()` only works with `Variant`, so `IsMissing(i)`will always return `False`.

Comment: See [IsMissing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445048%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Comment: You can make the function use a variant as parameter. Then IsMissing will work. There are hardly any penalties in using a variant instead of an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Function f(Optional i As Integer = 1) As Integer
   f = i
End Function
```

Comment: `i` could have 1 as a valid value.

Comment: i having a value of 1 is no problem in this case since the result should be 1.